Can a 37 total capacity setup do good with a 37 total capacity shortcage ss rear derailleur?
I've been asking this question for a few days now and I've been so curious about it
My setup is a 11-32t sprocket and a 50-34t crankset, the total of that is 37
The main question is in the title but here is another one, just like the first question said will it have any kind of slack while in total capacity and will any of the performance change like will it give uglier gear performance and shifting?

How many speeds? And what derailleur are you looking at (brand, model)?

I don't think that would work. Shimano road short cage (ss) derailleur capacity is closer to 29. Way below what you require.
With medium cage (gs) you would generally be ok but would need to check exact derailleur spec. You don't mention the model in your question.
In my experience derailleur specs are rather conservative and running at max capacity usually does not cause any shifting problem by itself. Exceeding max capacity is a minefield.

Art's right. That's a set up asking for trouble from the SS cage derailleur, which is overspecc'd in terms of the 32 tooth large cassette cog. So, despite the SS derailleurs'  reputation for crisper shifting performance within its specs, a setup like this could very well have slack chain in the small-small combo, the derailleur cage unable to gather up the slack from a properly sized chain wrapped around the large-large combo. That said, one could avoid those cross-chaining extremes to avoid the slack, and a long enough B-screw would allow the cage space to get the chain on the 32 tooth cog...

The last generation R7000 SS RD has a total capacity of 35t, maximum biggest cog 30t, FWIW. The OP's setup would be a bit outside the specs.
